# Module is not found

Tags: python, pip

I used this command line in the terminal to get the module:

```
$ pip install yahoo-finance
```

I used this code to check the module was imported correctly, but it says there no module called yahoo_finance

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print (yahoo.get_price())
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you get into the REPL (running python on the command line), run help(), then run "modules". It'll print a list of all the modules it can find.

Comment: compare your pip and python version with `python -V` and `pip -V`

Comment: Huh, on py2 it installs, but on py3 it says it installs, but isn't in the modules list.

Comment: @HackSaw Just installed it with Python3 and worked fine on my end.

Comment: Well, I  just discovered that on my Mac, I have two different versions of pip3, and the one higher in the path list doesn't have a python3 pointing at it. So , maybe make sure the paths to python and pip are the same. Use 'which'. 
That said, I still get an error running the code you have, so...

Comment: Starting to wonder if the API changed or was turned off...

Comment: Huh, yahoo-finance-1.40 was released in 2016. Maybe dead?

Comment: the API was listed December last year

Comment: @HackSaw I was having a similar problem with another module earlier so not sure if it's my end or the API

Comment: This thread suggests it was closed: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/44

Answer (score 4):

Check if you use the right version of python

`pip install` install library to modules of python 2 while your code is using python3.

Try to use

```
$ pip3 install yahoo-finance
```

Comment: I redid the command with your version and still getting an error saying (No module named 'yahoo_finance')

Comment: Yes it is python3

Comment: The package seems dead right now, even though, I can still run it on my end.
use `$ pip3 install yahoo-finance` then run `$ python3` then paste your code. You might want to check which pip3 and python3 you are using as other comment stated,. Or you might want to use virtualenv or pyenv as other answer stated to manage you environment.

Comment: Huh, I just found this: https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/, which describes a new service.

Comment: As i read, it is `unirest`, not `yahoo-finance` @HackSaw

Comment: Yep. It's what I found, assuming the problem is with yahoo. @yagizcandegirmenci seems to have found a more maintained version, yfinance.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that yahoo-finance doesn't works, because it's not maintained, latest commit for `yahoo-finance` package is 4 years ago. But also you can use a maintained one which is `yfinance`

To install yfinance with pip;

```
pip install yfinance
```

With conda installer;

```
conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance
```

You can find more info about `yfinance` in this [github repository](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend installing [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to take care of Python's installation. It will allow you to install Python (which will automatically come with its version of pip), and manage different Python versions in your system.

```
pyenv install 3.8.0
pyenv global 3.8.0  # sets your global Python to 3.8.0
```

For the time being, what you will want to do is use:

```
python -m pip install yahoo-finance
```

This will call the `pip` version for the specific `python` version that you are running under the `python` command -- which can be `python2` or `python3`, depending on how your `PATH` var is set.